# DDWRT Firewall Rule Not Working

Tags: router, vpn, firewall, iptables

I am using a Netgear router flashed with DD-WRT firmware running a constant VPN connection. I do not use any VLANS or any other firewall rules.

To help protect my IP address, I applied the following firewall rule but it does not seem to be blocking traffic when the VPN connection drops out.

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o tun1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun1 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -i tun1 -j REJECT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o tun1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: What netgear router, and what DDWRT revision?

Comment: Router is Netgear R8000. 
Firmware: DD-WRT v3.0-r33435M kongac (10/08/17)

Comment: I have had a few issues with their firewall on occasion - I used LEDE on my r8000 instead. https://lede-project.org/toh/hwdata/netgear/netgear_r8000

I much prefer the LEDE firewall GUI too.

Comment: Which interfaces are inside your bridge? You should block traffic going through them directly, something like